# Display JSON response with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, get

I need to display data from JSON response using Angularjs

When checking the response with DevTools i can see the results, but when it comes to diplay, it doesn't work

Controller :

```
MovieApp.controller('movieAdminCtrl',  ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
    $scope.movies=[];
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/movies').success(function(data) {
        $scope.movies = data;

    }); 

        }]);
```

Response : 
[image]

Display Code :

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="movie in movies"  >
                <td></td>

                <td >{{movie.title}}</td>
                <td >{{movie.actors}}</td>
                <td >{{movie.Created_date}}</td>
                <td><img ng-src="{{movie.poster}}" /></td>
```

Comment: can you pls post the complete html and angular code? may be something very small is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the **`data`** property of the response

```
 $http.get('http://localhost:3000/movies').success(function(data) {
        $scope.movies = data.data;
 });
```

Comment: post what you see inside $scope.movies .

Comment: How can i sse inside ? i tried with an alert just after   $scope.movies = data.data; but nothing happen

Comment: console.log (JSON.stingify(data)); and post here

Comment: Thanks it's working now it was a CORS problem with the api

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="movieAdminCtrl">

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
            <td></td>

            <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
            <td>{{movie.actors}}</td>
            <td>{{movie.Created_date}}</td>
            <td>
                <img ng-src="{{movie.poster}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            var MovieApp = angular.module('app', []);
            MovieApp.controller('movieAdminCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
                $scope.movies = [];
                $http.get('http://localhost:3000/movies').success(function (data) {
                    $scope.movies = data;

                });

            }]);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```